# How to loop nested maps in SASS

Tags: sass

I'm trying to loop nested maps in sass in order to create certain css variables for a list of themes.

I have a mape of themes like this:

```
$themes: (
    theme-1: (
        primary: (
            "el-background": #000,
            "el-background-hover": #0d0d0d,
            "el-color": #2c2f33,
            "el-link-color": #fff,
        ),
        secondary_1: (
            "el-background": #000,
            "el-background-hover": #ccc,
            "el-color": #f2f2f2,
            "el-link-color": #fff,
        )
    ),
    theme-2: (
        primary: (
            "el-background": #f90,
            "el-background-hover": #ccc,
            "el-color": #000,
            "el-link-color": #fff,
        ),
        secondary_1: (
            "el-background": #f2f2f2,
            "el-background-hover": #000,
            "el-color": #f2f2f2,
            "el-link-color": #fff,
        )
    )
);
```

I'm expecting a result like this in css:

```
.theme-1 {
    .primary {
        --el-background: ...;
        --el-background-hover: ...;
        --el-color: ...;
        --el-link-color: ...;
    }

    .secondary_1 {
        --el-background: ...;
        --el-background-hover: ...;
        --el-color: ...;
        --el-link-color: ...;
    }
}

.theme-2 {
    .primary {
        --el-background: ...;
        --el-background-hover: ...;
        --el-color: ...;
        --el-link-color: ...;
    }

    .secondary_1 {
        --el-background: ...;
        --el-background-hover: ...;
        --el-color: ...;
        --el-link-color: ...;
    }
}
```

How do I tweak this loop to achieve this? I think I need to wrap it in another `@each` but not sure how.

```
@mixin theme() {
    @each $theme, $map in $themes {
        .#{$theme} {
            @each $key,
            $value in $map {
                --#{$key}: #{$value};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add another loop to go over values in 'primary' and 'secondary_1'. Something like this:

```scss
@mixin theme() {
    @each $theme, $map in $themes {
        .#{$theme} {
            @each $key, $value in $map {
              .#{$key} {
                @each $varName, $varValue in $value {
                  --#{$varName}: #{$varValue};
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}

:root {
  @include theme();
}
```

Solution on [SCSS playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#eJy1k71ugzAUhXc/hZVkCFJcAZkKC0/QsWvlGrsgjB05ATVCfvf6hwRaKFIrcr34mu8ejo8ginaXgtb0nMA9gKZch6Jba+ukyhqr6/jI1oZy9I5J9aFkI/JNArdhGB4WEFTIlioH5nZNWSK5dEBMYnY8TgFeimqgGGMDEgzbMyVS5MbyW7SiaULIgmMW2/U3x2Dk2+ce/yt39rzKFWaTeEDiv0U1+6XMeVohdBCkAGR1+VkKH/0+gJ17lFFMCuj/igPc1fgEDdP/JT1j62nb+UM9OhwJVPRqxlvMG+oErNB30GsY7qfCSKXF6gU7I2b3ehfzstMpCBEymv2UNpfv7oM6neAaLPVD53caaAASJeXFvTkrBeFNTm/5pUB/AbSEBi4=)